# Difficult equation with three variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I thought up a math problem, and hope you all will find it interesting.

For positive integers a, b and c the following numbers are formed:

$x = 60a + 13b$ and $y = 60a + 11c$

Now I have to find all possibilities of $a, b$ and $c$ to which the following equation applies:

$$4x^2-y^2= 2020$$

and prove that there are no further solutions.

Thanks for all good answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint :**
$$4x^2-y^2=2020 \Longleftrightarrow (2x-y)(2x+y)=2020$$

Comment: I still don't understand. Could you please explain it to me again. Thank you. I'm not so good in maths.

Comment: $2x-y$ and $2x+y$ are integers, and they both divide $2020$... And $2020$ has not a lot of dividers ! You can check by hand all the possibilities, and deduce the corresponding values of $a$, $b$, $c$.

Comment: @Jonathan:  also $2x+y$ and $2x-y$ are both even or both odd.  As their product is even, they must both be even.  You can look for ways to factor $2020$ into two even numbers, cutting it down even further.

Comment: I have looked for the dividers of 2020. These are 1,2020 2,1010 4,505 5,404 10, 202 and 20,101. But at this moment moment I am not sure how can I check the possibilities. Yes  I know that I'm getting on your nerves, but I want really to understand. I understand the approach. Could you
show me the solution using a calculation method. That would really help me. Thanks in advance. Jonathan

Comment: Well, $2x-y$ and $2x+y$ must be two even dividers of $2020$, that multiply to $2020$ ! The only possibilities are $(2,1010)$ and $(10, 202)$.

Comment: Thank you all lot

Comment: Well I have an other question. I have tried find out what the variables a, b and c are but I came not to a really conclusion. Can you explain me how I can do that. Please help me again. I am bad in maths. I know that. Thank for your help.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I meant, can you explain me what method you tried ?

Comment: First off we have both equations : Number one 253 = 60a + 13b and Second one 504 = 60a +11 c That is right, or not

Comment: Then I have tried to form the equation so that is have one variable but I came not to a conclusion. Because always I have c or b.

Comment: How can I change the equations so that I have only one variable that I can determine

Comment: Your two equations are good (for the case where $2x-y=2$ and $2x+y=1010$). So $253 = 60a + 13b$. What are the possibilities for $a$ ?

Comment: Sorry I came also again not to real conclusion. Can you help me again.

Comment: From $253=60a+13b$, what are the different possibilities for $a$ ?

Comment: A must be 4 and b must be 1. Is that right. Because they are integers.

Comment: Yes, you got it

Comment: And c is must be 24

Comment: Good, don't forget that you have also the case $2x+y=10$ and $2x-y=202$ to check.

Comment: Yes I will do that. Thanks again for your help. You are the best.

Comment: The second case is false. A can never be an integer there.

Comment: You are right :)